# pyautogui functions not working on software instalation

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pyautogui

I'am trying to automatize a software instalation with python and pyautogui, but pyautogui don't click, don't press, just find the location:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import pyperclip

for window in pyautogui.getWindows():
    pyautogui.getWindow(window).minimize()

##Open the directory where we can find the .exe
pyautogui.hotkey("win","r")
pyautogui.press("\\")
pyautogui.press("\\")
pyperclip.copy("ts1/publico/Meus Documentos/Equipes Qualidade/Automação/Aplicativos/Folha/Sefip 8.4")
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl","v")
pyautogui.press("enter")

##Take the .exe position and click on it.
executavel = None
while executavel is None:
    executavel = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("executavel.png", grayscale=False)
executalvelX, executavelY = pyautogui.center(executavel)
pyautogui.click(executalvelX, executavelY, clicks=2)

##The program opens

##Find the button "YES", and click on it(The Script find the button, but pyautogui.click(), pyautogui.moveTo(), pyautogui.press() don't work!)
botaoSim = None
while botaoSim is None:
    botaoSim = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("botaosim.png", grayscale=False)
botaoSimX, botaoSimY = pyautogui.center(botaoSim)


for _ in range(4):
    next1 = None
    while next1 is None:
        next1 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("next.png", grayscale=False)
    next1X, next1Y = pyautogui.center(next1)
    pyautogui.click(next1X, next1Y)
```

Follow the 'YES' button:
[image]

Why the functions don't work?